# English to Telugu and Telugu to English dictionary database

Tags: data-request, language, india, dictionary, books

**Data:** Database of Telugu to English and vice versa language dictionary

**Context:** Need to make a Telugu to English and vice versa dictionary app.There should be quite some public domain dictionaries for Telugu language by now. The first one I can think of is C.P.Brown English to Telugu dictionary.

**Region:** Telugu is an Indian language spoken in Andhra Pradesh and Telangana states.

**License:** Any license that allows me to redistribute the data in an application. But when it comes to Indian dictionaries the only data that meets the criteria would be public domain since the copy of CC licenses and Open Data is not big in India.

**Format:** I am okay with Screen scraping as long as the license of the source allows redistribution. But I would want to screen scrape and the distribute it in an offline available manner, not screen scrape live in the end product

**Authority:** Preferably a database of a dictionary which has been published offline, but not mandatory.

**Requirements:** Non-image formats and plain text format, preferably in database format

**Non-Answers:** 
I searched for "Telugu dictionary" on the Internet Archive and there are a few dictionaries in scanned format, but many of them were modern dictionaries which were probably uploaded without the copyright holders' consent.
The few of them that were public domain are in image format and the words aren't always clear and the auto OCR didn't OCR the Telugu words and only OCRed the English words. The Telugu words are just gibberish.

Answer (score 3):

How about Wiktionary?  https://te.wiktionary.org

Bulk downloads are available: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/tewiktionary/

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/tewiktionary/latest/

Parsing wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Parsing

The license is permissive for redistribution: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Copyrights

And because you are looking for translations, you can use internal wiktionary links between words, for example, from the `te` subdomain to the `en` one.

Comment: The Telugu Wiktionary uses the Charles Philip Brown dictionary data from 1853, and it has extensive copying issues where English words are joined when they shouldn't be (hisgiving, entertainno, etc.). That said, it may still be the best we've got right now T_T